# Objective C do while loop not exiting on false condition

Tags: objective-c, while-loop, do-while

The loop is supposed to take in names (and convert to NSString) until "done" is entered, but instead it just continues. I have two different checks inside the loop based on solutions from similar questions but neither of them work.

```
NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
char t[150];
NSString *str = @"";
do{
    printf("Input a name (enter \"DONE\" to exit)\n");
    fgets(t, 150, stdin);
    if (strcmp(t, "DONE") ==0)
        break;
    str = [NSString stringWithCString: t encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if ([str caseInsensitiveCompare: @"DONE"] == NSOrderedSame)
        break;
    [names addObject: str];
} while ([str caseInsensitiveCompare: @"DONE"] != NSOrderedSame);
```

Additionally, when I alter it to exit when str does *not* equal "done", the loop successfully exits. What could be wrong?
(I am new to Objective C so if the answer is obvious I apologize.)

Comment: Are you sure that the program actually enters the if statement? Try using the debugger to check it. It might be that the if statement is returning false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fgets()` function will give you a line of input, and this bit is important, *including the trailing newline character!*

And, since `DONE\n` is not the same as `DONE`, it won't exit the loop.

One way to handle this is to remove the newline yourself, something like:

```
fgets(t, 150, stdin);
size_t tlen = strlen (t);
if ((tlen > 0) && (t[tlen-1] == '\n'))
    t[tlen-1] = '\0';
```

Alternatively, you could get rid of *all* white space at the end of the line (including the newline) with something like:

```
fgets(t, 150, stdin);
size_t tlen = strlen (t);
while ((tlen > 0) && isspace (t[tlen-1]))
    t[--tlen] = '\0';
```